# moving class-level dynamic method creation into a module in ruby

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

I'm working on an application where I have a plugin-style architecture with multiple abstract classes that define an API, and specific implementations with subclasses that provide methods for the attributes defined on the abstract classes. Think of a generic database adapter with abstract classes like Connection, Table, Column, etc. and specific subclasses of these for a particular database.

In an attempt to be DRY, I declare the attributes of each abstract class (with default values) as a class constant Array called `ATTRIBUTES`. Since ruby doesn't support true abstract classes, I dynamically create methods that raise an exception if they're called on the abstract class. For example:

```
module MyApplication
  class Operation
    ATTRIBUTES = { name: '', parameters: [], type: :void }
    ATTRIBUTES.keys.each do |a|
      str = "Method '%s' called on abstract 'MyApplication::Operation' class"
      define_method(a) { raise (str % a) }
      define_method("#{a}=") { |x| raise (str % "#{a}=") }
    end
  end
end
```

I hard code the class name in the message because I can't use the name of the current class, since it might be a subclass of the abstract `Operation` class, and I want the message to be clear that the method being called is on the abstract class.

I have more than a handful of these abstract classes, and I've copied nearly the same code into each one to create these stub methods (only the attributes list and class name are different). I've tried numerous ways to put this code into a module that I can include (or extend?) from each abstract class, but my brain is now folded in on itself trying to sort out the meta-programming details of how to get this to work. :)

Does anyone have the magic bullet to pull this common, class-level (but instance method-making) code into a module to avoid repeating the same code over and over?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do what you want:

```
module PluginHelpers
  def stub_required_methods(*method_names)
    method_names.each do |method_name|
      define_method(method_name) do
        raise NotImplementedError, "Method #{__method__} must be implemented in #{self.class}"
      end
    end
  end
end

class A
  class B
    class C
      extend PluginHelpers
      stub_required_methods(:foo, :bar)
    end
  end
end

# usage
A::B::C.new.foo # => NotImplementedError: Method foo must be implemented in A::B::C
```

Comment: Unless I'm still confused, won't this add the stub methods to the *module*, which would make them all defined on all classes that end up extending PluginHelpers? I feel like one of the (many) iterations of attempts I made to get this working ended up having that undesired side effect.

Comment: Not sure I understand your concern. I would just take the code that I've written and try it out for your specific use case.

Comment: I was having trouble getting it working, but it turned out to be a problem with paths and 'require'. Seems to be working now, so thanks for the help!

Comment: By the way, my question/confusion about where the method would be added had to do with some confusion about what `self` would be set to inside the module definition. I was a little surprised that `self` inside of `PluginHelpers` was `A::B::C`. Not what I expected.

Comment: Glad it worked out! To really understand this stuff, I suggest reading Metaprogramming Ruby by Paolo Perrotta. Enjoy!

Comment: I'm about 3/4 of the way through Metaprogramming Ruby right now. Such a great explanation of the inner workings of Ruby's object model, and filled with some really slick and practical tricks. Thanks for the rec!

Comment: Glad you are enjoying it!! :)